# Indexing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, methods

So, I have this bit of code here that I'm working on for a school

```
def sem1Sort(semester1, selectionSEM1):
    for semester1["1"] in semester1:
        if semester1["1"] in selectionSEM1:
             print semester1["1"]

def main():     
    selectionSEM1 = ["a", "t", "b", "f", "d", "e"]

    semester1 = {"1": ['a', 'e', 't', 'x', 'l', 'y'], "2": ['b', 'f', 'h', 'm', 'r', 'd'] ,
    "3": ['a', 'b', 'j', 'k', 'o', 'q', 'u'], "4": ['c', 'l', 't', 'z', 'd', 'f'],
    "5": [], "6": [], "7": [], "8": []}


main()
```

So in the sem1Sort(): method, it should grab the semester1 list, as well as the artificial selectionSEM1 list. After that for each different index in the list of semester["1"], if it is in selectionSEM1, it should print it, correct?

Comment: It's not even remotely clear to me what you're trying to do in `sem1Sort`. `for semester1["1"] in semester1` isn't legal code. Can you show what your expected output is? Also, are any of the empty lists you're creating relevant to this question? If not, you should delete them so that they don't distract from the actually relevant bits of your example code.

Comment: @Blckknght, `for semester1["1"] in semester1` is legal code.

Comment: `"After that for each different index in the list of semester["1"]"` -I do not found any `semester` in your code. clarify your question more.

Comment: @John: Ah, you're right. It's not invalid code, just very foolish (it destroys the original contents of `semester1["1"]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is "How do I get the classes that are found in both the student's selections and the classes available for a semester?". Without changing the way your data is formatted try this filtering method.

```
def sem1Sort(semester1, selectionSEM1):
    for period in semester1:
        if period == '1':
            for cls in semester1[period]:
                if cls in selectionSEM1:
                     print cls
```

alternately since you were only checking for the first period

```
def sem1Sort(semester1, selectionSEM1):
    print '\n'.join([cls for cls in semester1['1'] if cls in selectionSEM1])
```

Comment: Why loop over `semester1`'s keys, when you could just do `for cls in semester1["1"]` directly?

Comment: @Blckknght, this answer doesn't change any of his method signatures or the way he formatted his data. With some refactoring I'm sure a much saner solution could be derived.

Comment: No, that's fine. My point is that looping over `semester1`'s keys only to test if the one you've pulled is equal to `"1"` is silly. Just plug that key in directly!